# Functions to filter missing values in SQL and change them to null values

Tags: sql, casting, filtering

Which SQL query string or function could I use to filter "zero" values from a dataset and change them to "null" values?

I tried to run a query to filter the "zero" values in a dataset and change them to "null" values, but I couldn't.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried, please?

Comment: Hello!
I'm completing the Google Data Analytics Certificate program, and they propose a problem situation in SQL. As I'm new to this website, I used that example to learn how to ask questions and check for feedback.  
I'm going to save the information for the future.
Thanks for your collaboration!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nullif`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-comparison-functions/sql-nullif/) which returns null if both values match, otherwise it returns the first value.

```
select
  some_int,
  nullif(some_int, 0),
  some_text,
  nullif(some_text, '0')
from some_table
```

`nullif` is specific to your problem. More generically you'd use a [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

```
select
  some_int,
  case some_int
    when 0 then null
    else some_int
  end as "case",
  some_text,
  case some_text
    when '0' then null
    else some_text
  end as "case"
from some_table;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/bqLGRZWB).